# JS Browser Update jQuery Plugin/Code Snippet

Tags: javascript, browser, upgrade

I'm looking for a code snippet or jQuery plugin that detects a user's browser and whether it's out of date and displays message.  Ideally, it would need to meet the following requirements:

- Unobtrusive
- Configurable text
- Multiple browser support
- Configurable minimum browser versions

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will get you pointed in the right direction: http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/

**EDIT**

Here's a few more:

jReject: http://jreject.turnwheel.com/

sevenup: http://code.google.com/p/sevenup/

Answer (score 5):

There is also another javascript that can be useful for this: http://browser-update.org/